# Entity not getting saved in database even though getting 204 as HTTP Status code

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, guice, dropwizard

I'm using JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 4.3.0.Final along with Google Guice 3.0 with dropwizard framework. In my Resource class, I have applied @Transactional annotation at the top.

```
@Path("/users")
@Slf4j
@Transactional
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UsersResource {

    @PUT
    @Timed
    @Path("/{userId}/userAddress")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void setUserAddress(@Valid SetUserAddressRequest request,
           @PathParam("userId") String userId) {
           if (!userId.equals(request.getUserId())) {
                throw new BadRequestException(Constants.USERID_ID_DO_NOT_MATCH);
           }
           request.setUserId(userId);
           setUserAddressCommandProvider
           .get()
           .withRequest(request)
           .run();
     }
}
```

My run function in command class looks like this

```
private User getUserByUserId(String userId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.getUser(userId);
    if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
        return optionalUser.get();
    }
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException(Constants.COULD_NOT_FIND_USER);
}

 public Void run() throws ResourceNotFoundException, WebApplicationException {
     User user = getUserByUserId(request.getUserId());
     String address = request.getAddress();
     if (user.getAddress() != null) {
        throw new ResourceConflictException(Constants.ADDRESS_ALREADY_EXISTS);
     }
     user.setAddress(address);
     user.setUpdatedAt(new Date());
     return null;
 }
```

The problem is that most of the times address gets saved but sometimes it doesn't even though I'm getting 204 as response code. Any pointers on how to debug it would be much appreciated.

Update: When I turn the debug mode on, I see this exception in logs

```
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl: Exception clearing
 maxRows/queryTimeout [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement 
 with address: "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@76eb0f79: EXCEPTION: 
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
 No operations allowed after statement closed." is closed.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `@UnitOfWork` annotation on the `setUserAddress` method? https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/hibernate.html